# Haskell space leak in implementation of BFS

Tags: haskell, memory-leaks, space, breadth-first-search

I have been banging my head against a Haskell space leak (of the stack overflow kind, naturally) for a few straight days.  It's frustrating because I'm attempting to mimic the BFS algorithm straight from CLR, which is not naturally recursive.  NB: I have enabled BangPatterns and I have put a bang in front of every possible place where one can go, in an attempt to branch-and-bound this problem, with no effect.  I have battled through space leaks before, and I am loth to give up and cry for help on this one, but at this point I'm stuck. I love coding in Haskell, and I understand the Zen of functional programming pretty well, but debugging space leaks is about as much fun as rolling around on a floor full of thumbtacks.

That said, my trouble appears to be a space leak of the typical "accumulator" kind.  The stack evidently builds up around calls to bfs' in the code below.  Any space-leak protips much appreciated.

```
import qualified Data.Map as M
import qualified Data.IntSet as IS
import qualified Data.Sequence as S
import qualified Data.List as DL

data BfsColor = White | Gray | Black deriving Show
data Node =
Node {
  neighbors :: !IS.IntSet,
  color     :: !BfsColor,
  depth     :: !Int
   }

type NodeID = Int
type NodeQueue = S.Seq NodeID
type Graph = M.Map NodeID Node

bfs :: Graph -> NodeID -> Graph
bfs graph start_node =
  bfs' (S.singleton start_node) graph

bfs' :: NodeQueue -> Graph -> Graph
bfs' !queue !graph
  | S.null queue = graph
  | otherwise =
  let (u,q1) = pop_left queue
      Node children _ n = graph M.! u
      (g2,q2) = IS.fold (enqueue_child_at_depth $ n+1) (graph,q1) children
      g3 = set_color u Black g2
  in bfs' q2 g3

enqueue_child_at_depth :: Int -> NodeID -> (Graph, NodeQueue)
                                        -> (Graph, NodeQueue)
enqueue_child_at_depth depth child (graph,!queue)  =
  case get_color child graph of
    White     -> (set_color child Gray $ set_depth child depth graph,
                   queue S.|> child)
    otherwise -> (graph,queue)

pop_left :: NodeQueue -> (NodeID, NodeQueue)
pop_left queue =
  let (a,b) = S.splitAt 1 queue
  in (a `S.index` 0, b)

set_color :: NodeID -> BfsColor -> Graph -> Graph
set_color node_id c graph =
  M.adjust (\node -> node{color=c}) node_id graph

get_color :: NodeID -> Graph -> BfsColor
get_color node_id graph = color $ graph M.! node_id

set_depth :: NodeID -> Int -> Graph -> Graph
set_depth node_id d graph =
  M.adjust (\node -> node{depth=d}) node_id graph
```

Comment: Your code is very hard to read and understand. I recommend to factor out the graph abstraction a bit, introducing `type NodeId = Int` and functions like `neighbors :: NodeId -> Graph -> [NodeId]` and so on. To fix a space leak, it is imperative that your code is as simple as possible.

Comment: Fair enough, and thank you Heinrich; here is some expansion:

Comment: One thing to remember is that overuse of strict annotations may cause memory spikes rather than ameliorate them. If you have a huge structure - it is going to be huge if you force all its elements.

Comment: CLR here means what? Microsoft's Common Language Runtime?

Comment: Cormen Leiserson Rivest. But I can see now that CLR has your definition much more often here.  I have consequently removed the tag.

Comment: You missed Stein.  I've always heard it referred to as CLRS

Comment: Now I'm dated. Stein was added since the 2nd ed. and I didn't notice

Answer (score 3):

That looks much easier to understand. (You can still shrink the code by 1/2, though.)

Now, the nature of the space leak becomes apparent. Namely, the one thing that is never evaluated is the *depth*. It will pile up to a big expression `1+1+...`. You can remove all the bang patterns and add a single one at

```
enqueue_child_at_depth !depth child (graph,queue)
```

to get rid of the space leak.

(Further code tips: You can replace the `IS.IntSet` by a simple list. The queue is best deconstructed and reconstructed along the lines of

```
go depth qs graph = case viewl qs of
    EmptyL  -> graph
    q :< qs ->
        let
            qs' = (qs ><) . Seq.fromList
                . filter (\q -> isWhite q graph)
                . neighbors q $ graph
        in ...
```

)

Comment: Thank you again Heinrich. I will study that further. (As a Haskell novice, I would be grateful to read any shrinkage tips you might have if you felt like typing in a couple of them).

Comment: update: Nevermind, I'm having fun working at it myself! regards, c

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if would be very helpful if you could provide some simple test case (in the form of code) which demonstrates how this thing stack overflows.
Without it I, personally, can only speculate on the subject of reason for that.

As a speculation: is `IS.fold` strict enough? Well, for example the following simplest code stack overflows as well (GHC with -O2):

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
import qualified Data.IntSet as IS

test s = IS.fold it 1 s
    where it !e !s = s+e

main = print $ test (IS.fromList [1..1000000])
```

The overflow problem with this code can be hackafixed (is there a better way?) like that:

```
test s = foldl' it 1 (IS.toList s)
    where it !e !s = s+e
```

Maybe you want to look at `IS.fold` in your code as well.

Comment: Thank you Ed'ka. I thought of that and fixing it didn't help, so I left the code as is (though I note that on haskell.org there are feature requests to add strict folds to Maps and IntSets, among other things, soon, so we're not alone).